# Generating unique string per each row while the code doesn't exists in the another table

Tags: sql-server

I have to generate a unique 3 character string (could be text and number) per each row of data but only if the same code doesn't already exists in the another table.

The new column will not be stored in any database and just needs to be generated on demand.

I was using:

```
SELECT Name, SurName,UNQCode =LEFT(NEWID(),3)
FROM Table
```

Result:

```
Name    SurName UNQCode
George  Colon        781
Robert  Studer       297
Thomas  White        A44
```

The format is fine but I need to guarantee that the code that was generated doesn't exist in another table:

```
Select Code from Table123
```

Result:

```
Code 
177
21F
585
63C
696
9EF
DA4
056
```

Comment: there aren't that many 3 character codes! Many less than there are people.

Comment: There can be around 50k combinations which should be enough

Comment: The problem becomes as you approach your 50k generating a new unique value becomes more and more problematic as the potential number of iterations increases. And if you hit the wall you can end up in an endless loop. If you really want to use this approach maybe create a table of available values first, then delete that row when you use it.

Comment: Have you considered generating a table with all possible combos?  You could then tag each id, as it is consumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider [the code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d724ee/2)

```
CREATE TABLE #Char
(
    [Value] CHAR(1)
);

CREATE TABLE Codes
(
    [Code] CHAR(3)
);

INSERT #Char
VALUES
('0'),
('1'),
('2'),
('3'),
('4'),
('5'),
('6'),
('7'),
('8'),
('9'),
('A'),
('B'),
('C'),
('D'),
('E'),
('F'),
('G'),
('H'),
('I'),
('J'),
('K'),
('L'),
('M'),
('N'),
('O'),
('P'),
('Q'),
('R'),
('S'),
('T'),
('U'),
('V'),
('W'),
('X'),
('Y'),
('Z');

INSERT Codes
SELECT
         T.[Code]
    FROM
      (SELECT
               A.[Value] + B.[Value] + C.[Value] [Code]
          FROM
               #Char A
             CROSS JOIN
               #Char B
             CROSS JOIN
               #Char C) T
    ORDER BY
         RAND();

SELECT COUNT([Code]) FROM [Codes];
```

You'll see that there are precisely 46656 permutations.

Now that you have a table of all possible permutations you'll be able to get all unused codes like this,

```
SELECT [Code] FROM [Codes]
EXCEPT
SELECT [Code] FROM [Table123]
```

Bear in mind, that as `[Table123]` grows this will save you lots of calls to `NEWID()` since there are literally billions of Unique Identifiers with the same first three characters.

There are numerous things you could do to the [Code] table to optimise the performance of code assigning, like adding a bit field to indicate if code has been used.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use this

Answer (score 0):

Around 50k combinations is enough you say?

Well you could do something like this then (note I am not recommending that you actually do anything like this):

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (code CHAR(3));
--Pre-load five code values that we don't want to see again
INSERT INTO @table1 SELECT LEFT(NEWID(), 3);
INSERT INTO @table1 SELECT LEFT(NEWID(), 3);
INSERT INTO @table1 SELECT LEFT(NEWID(), 3);
INSERT INTO @table1 SELECT LEFT(NEWID(), 3);
INSERT INTO @table1 SELECT LEFT(NEWID(), 3);
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (name VARCHAR(255));
--Put in a couple of names
INSERT INTO @table2 SELECT 'John Smith';
INSERT INTO @table2 SELECT 'Mary Stuart';
WITH NewCodes AS (
    SELECT 1 AS row_id, LEFT(NEWID(), 3) AS code
    UNION ALL
    SELECT row_id + 1 AS row_id, LEFT(NEWID(), 3) AS code FROM NewCodes nc WHERE row_id <= 50000),
DistinctCodes AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT code FROM NewCodes),
UniqueCodes AS (
    SELECT
        dc.code,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS row_id
    FROM
        DistinctCodes dc
        LEFT JOIN @table1 t1 ON t1.code = dc.code
    WHERE
        t1.code IS NULL),
Names AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS row_id
    FROM
        @table2 t2)
SELECT
    n.name,
    uc.code
FROM
    Names n
    INNER JOIN UniqueCodes uc ON uc.row_id = n.row_id OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

It's actually quite an interesting problem, and one that might require a non-set based approach.  I can see how you could do this easily in a loop, but I thought I would take a stab at a set based approach anyway.  Essentially the problem is "how many new, random codes do I need to fulfil the names without duplicating codes, and without reusing codes used in the past?".